# Android ViewModel has no zero argument constructor when calling .observe() on a sharedViewModel

Tags: android, dependency-injection, viewmodel, assisted-inject

I have the following classes:

The ViewModel

```
class MealPlanViewModel @AssistedInject constructor(private val mealPlanRepository: MealPlanRepository, @Assisted private val canteenId: String) : ViewModel() {


    // AssistedInject code for using ViewModel injection with runtime parameters
    @AssistedInject.Factory
    interface AssistedFactory {
        fun create (canteenId: String): MealPlanViewModel
    }

    companion object {
        fun provideFactory(assistedFactory: AssistedFactory, canteenId: String): ViewModelProvider.Factory = object : ViewModelProvider.Factory {
            override fun <T : ViewModel?> create(modelClass: Class<T>): T {
                return assistedFactory.create(canteenId) as T
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The parent fragment:

```
class MealPlanFragment : Fragment() {

    val canteenId = "mensa"

    @Inject
    lateinit var viewModelAssistedFactory: MealPlanViewModel.AssistedFactory

    private val viewModel: MealPlanViewModel by viewModels {
        MealPlanViewModel.provideFactory(viewModelAssistedFactory, canteenId)
    }

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        val binding = FragmentMealPlanBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
        val tabLayout = binding.tabLayout
        val viewPager = binding.viewPager

        viewPager.adapter = MealPlanPagerAdapter(childFragmentManager, lifecycle)

        return binding.root
    }

}
```

and the child fragment attached to the parent fragment by viewpager

```
@AndroidEntryPoint
class DayFragment : Fragment() {

private val viewModel: MealPlanViewModel by viewModels(

        ownerProducer = {requireParentFragment()}

    )

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {

        val binding = FragmentDayBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)

        viewModel.getMealPlanByDay(...).observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer {

             ...

        })

        return binding.root
    }



    companion object {

        @JvmStatic
        fun newInstance(position: Int) =
            DayFragment().apply {
                arguments = Bundle().apply {
                    putInt(POSITION, position)
                }
            }

    }

}
```

The call of

```
viewModel.getMealPlanByDay(...).observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer {

})
```

leads to the following error:
Cannot create an instance of class MealPlanViewModel
has no zero argument constructor

But if I don't use AssistedInject to create the ViewModel in the parent fragment and instantiate it like in the following instead I don't get the "has no zero argument constructor" in the child fragment.

```
val bundle: Bundle = ...
val mealPlanRepository = ...

val mealPlanViewModelFactory = MealPlanViewModelFactory(mealPlanRepository, canteenId, this, bundle)
val viewModel = ViewModelProvider(this, mealPlanViewModelFactory).get(MealPlanViewModel::class.java)
```

Any ideas on why that is and how to fix this while still using AssistedInject?

Answer (score 0):

By [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65352324/view-model-initialization-using-by-viewmodels-vs-viewmodelproviderthis-ge), the Kotlin property delegate AssistedInject `by viewModels()` lazily instantiates the view model. So if you don't reference the view model in the parent fragment `onCreateView()` or earlier before inflating the child fragment, the view model won't be created in time for the child fragment to access in its `onCreateView()`. Using `ViewModelProvider` instantiates the view model as soon as the parent fragment is created.

Thanks for the question, I ran into the same problem and resolved it the same way you did.