# whats the difference between viewModel and viewModels class

Tags: android, android-architecture-components, android-viewmodel

In this code I am creating a reference to the `GameViewModel` class which extends the `ViewModel` class
I know why we are delegating the responsibility to `viewModels()` but I want to know what actually is this `viewModels` and how it is different from `ViewModel`

```
private val viewModel: GameViewModel by viewModels()
```

Comment: I think this might give you some ideas: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65352324/view-model-initialization-using-by-viewmodels-vs-viewmodelproviderthis-ge

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You compare kotlin delegate function( by viewModels()) and ViewModel class together, open sources i think that will help you better understand.

Comment: can u pls elaborate a bit

Comment: Yes of course , i guess you know about MVVM architecture , so ViewModel is VM, before MVVM we used MVC or MVP , ViewModel(VM) has a bit more benefits than Controller (C) or Presenter (P), For example ViewModel can survive configurationChange( Screen Rotation, Screen Size , Theme) changes, https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel check out this link for more details about ViewModel.
 Now i wanna talk about viewModels(), viewModels() is a kotlin delegate method which are creating a new instance of ViewModel, so thats all.
I hope I've been of help.