# Using view model to pass data between fragments

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm new to Android development and making an Android map app. Right now, I have three fragments: one is the map, and two are recycler view lists of locations. All of them are in the nav host in my main activity. What I want to do is click the location in the list and it takes me to the map fragment and put a marker on the map.

My idea is to set the view model in my list fragment and get the view model in my map fragment.

My view model:

```
private val _location = MutableLiveData<Location>()
val location: LiveData<Location> = _location

fun setLocation(location: Location) {
    _location.value = location
}
```

My click listener in location fragment:

```
private var clickListenerImpl = object : LocationsAdapter.OnClickListener {
    override fun onNameClick(location: Location) {
        viewModel.setLocation(location)
        view?.findNavController()?.navigate(
            LocationsFragmentDirections.actionLocationsToMap()
        )
    }
}
```

My on map ready callback:

```
viewModel.location.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, { location ->
    googleMap.addMarker(
        MarkerOptions()
            .position(LatLng(location.lat, location.lng))
    )
})
```

Am I using the view model right? I couldn't get my view model data in the map fragment, nor my other list fragment. I tried to use log in both location and map fragment. It seems it sets the view model in location fragment properly, but the map fragment still thinks it's null, so it won't update. Or is there a better way to do this instead of using the view model?

---

Thanks, Everybody. I really want to give all an upvote, but my reputation is too low to do that.

Although I really want to use ViewModel, I still couldn't get it to work in the activity scope. Maybe when I initiate it in a new fragment, it overwrites its old value? I don't know.

```
private val viewModel: LocationViewModel by activityViewModels {
    LocationViewModelFactory((requireActivity().application as LocationApplication).repository)
}
```

My solution is changed to use SafeArgs. It requires an extra step to convert latitude and longitude to float type but gets the job done.

Comment: do you find solution ,,because I face the same problem

Comment: Bundles and intents are not working for me so the ViewModelProvider is the better option: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70135731/passing-data-through-navigation-between-fragments-android-studio/78214917#78214917.

Answer (score 1):

Two ways of achieving sharing ViewModel data between fragments comes to mind.

1. Use an activityViewModels(). This will keep the ViewModel alive as long as the parent Activity is alive. See [Share Data Between Fragments Using ViewModels](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel#sharing) .

`private val model: SharedViewModel by activityViewModels()`

Edit: Using by activityViewModels with a ViewModelFactory

```
private val model: SharedViewModel by activityViewModels() {
   ExampleViewModelFactory(
     repository
   )
}
```

2. Second way is to instantiate a ViewModel in the Activity then in each Fragment grab that object to use. Almost like a Singleton.

Comment: Hi, I look this article. I can't use it because I'm also using Room. So I have to initiate ViewModel is by using ViewModel Factory with an argument of my repository class. But I think your second way is a good idea. Let me try it.

Comment: I updated the answer with an example of using` activityViewModels()` with a ViewModel Factory. Just pass the same instance of your repository class into the Factory. You can again use the idea of instantiating the repository class in the activity, using a Singleton, and/or if you really want to get advanced a DI framework like Dagger.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using an activity scoped ViewModel? You need to use an activity scoped ViewModel or nav scoped viewModel for this to work. If you use a fragment scoped ViewModel in your map and list fragments. The fragment would get different instances of your ViewModel.
In my opinion, I'd simply just pass the location data as a fragment argument instead of sharing a ViewModel.

Comment: Thanks, I see. I might not be using activity scoped ViewModel. You say pass the data as a fragment argument do you mean to use SafeArgs or bundle?

Comment: SafeArgs are you are already using navigation components.

Answer (score 0):

The `ViewModel` works like this:

1. Each `ViewModel` is (shold be) bound to a single `LifeCycleOwner`, which refers to `Fragment` or `Activity`. In other words, Each `ViewModel` is bound to a single `Fragment` or `Activity`.
2. For sharing (`ViewModel's`) data between `Fragments`, use **[SharedViewModel](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel#sharing)** pattern, the idea is, this `ViewModel` will be bound to the outer (parent) `Activity`, and for each its child `Fragment` you can get this `ViewModel` instance by using:

   ```
    ViewModelProvider(requireActivity()).get(MainViewModel::class.java)
   ```

Comment: Hi, because I'm also using Room. I followed this Codelab: https://developer.android.com/codelabs/android-room-with-a-view-kotlin#9. So my ViewModel is bound to an Application like this private val wordViewModel: WordViewModel by viewModels {
    WordViewModelFactory((application as WordsApplication).repository)
} Is this the reason I can't get my instance?

Comment: @tdyin This may help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65352324/view-model-initialization-using-by-viewmodels-vs-viewmodelproviderthis-ge.

Comment: Oh, I see. They're the same. Thanks.